# Error junit 4.12 and class path

Tags: android, junit, junit4

Hey i have encountered this problem in android studio 3.0.1
Please give the solution.
I have tired to resolve but its not of any use.
 [image]

Comment: 1. Check if internet is working,  2. Check if the entries of dependencies you provided are correct including their version number.